# Is there any way to put a checkmark beside a context menu in wp7 / silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I have a several MenuItem's inside a ContextMenu in my wp7 app using silverlight. In a particular scenario, I need to place a checkmark beside one of the items.

Is there any way to do this?

I would settle for adding a Image control to the right of it if I had to.

I've even tried doing this:

```
CheckBox box = new CheckBox();
menuItem.Items.Add(box);
```

but got a NotImplementedException.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy way to get this working. I bound the menu item's Header text property in xaml to a string property which adds the unicode checkmark character (0x2714) if the flag is set.

```
<toolkit:MenuItem 
      Header="{Binding InvertedCommandHeader}"              
      Click="onCommandInvert"
/>
```

I defined the dependency properties in my data context object like so:

```
public const string InvertedPropertyTag = "Inverted";
public static readonly DependencyProperty InvertedProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        InvertedPropertyTag,
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(MyData),
        new PropertyMetadata(false));
public bool Inverted
{
  get
  {
    return (bool)GetValue(InvertedProperty);
  }
  set
  {
    SetValue(InvertedProperty, value);

    InvertedCommandHeader = value ?
      Strings.IDST_MENUITEM_INVERTED + "  \u2714" :
      Strings.IDST_MENUITEM_INVERTED;
  }
}

public const string InvertedCommandHeaderPropertyTag = "InvertedCommandHeader";
public static readonly DependencyProperty InvertedCommandHeaderProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        InvertedCommandHeaderPropertyTag,
        typeof(string),
        typeof(MyData),
        new PropertyMetadata(
          Strings.IDST_MENUITEM_INVERTED));
public string InvertedCommandHeader
{
  get
  {
    return (string)GetValue(InvertedCommandHeaderProperty);
  }
  set
  {
    SetValue(InvertedCommandHeaderProperty, value);
  }
}
```

When the menu item is selected, I toggle the checkmark property.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a listbox to contextmenu and then add checkbox to the listbox. I have not implemented but you can give it a try.